# Does appium-dotnet-driver support .net core 2.x?

Tags: .net-core, appium

I am trying to use Appium donet webdriver in .net core framework and giving me warning for Appium.WebDriver, Castle.Core and Selenium.Support. Do we have support with .net core?

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar for the WinDriver. I was able to convert the GettingStartedWinDriver solution from Automate the planet. See [their GitHub](https://github.com/AutomateThePlanet/AutomateThePlanet-Learning-Series/tree/master/WebDriver-Series).

Below screenshot shows the project properties and dependencies used:
[image: This screenshot]
As you can see Appium.WebDriver (4.0.05-beta) is being referenced to make this work. That was key to make it work on .net Core 2.1. So be sure to investigate this in your effort to make this work for the WebDriver.

And this is the implementation:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using System;

namespace GettingStartedWinDriverDotNetCore2Dot1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class CalculatorTests
    {
        private WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> _driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void TestInit()
        {
            AppiumOptions appOptions = new AppiumOptions();

            appOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
            appOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            _driver = 
                new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appOptions);
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            if (_driver != null)
            {
                _driver.Quit();
                _driver = null;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Addition()
        {
            _driver.FindElementByName("Five").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByName("Plus").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByName("Seven").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByName("Equals").Click();

            var calculatorResult = GetCalculatorResultText();
            Assert.AreEqual("12", calculatorResult);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Division()
        {
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num8Button").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num8Button").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("divideButton").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num1Button").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("num1Button").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("equalButton").Click();

            Assert.AreEqual("8", GetCalculatorResultText());
        }

        [Test]
        public void Multiplication()
        {
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Nine']").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Multiply by']").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Nine']").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@Name='Equals']").Click();

            Assert.AreEqual("81", GetCalculatorResultText());
        }

        [Test]
        public void Subtraction()
        {
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"num9Button\"]").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"minusButton\"]").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"num1Button\"]").Click();
            _driver.FindElementByXPath("//Button[@AutomationId=\"equalButton\"]").Click();

            Assert.AreEqual("8", GetCalculatorResultText());
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase("One", "Plus", "Seven", "8")]
        [TestCase("Nine", "Minus", "One", "8")]
        [TestCase("Eight", "Divide by", "Eight", "1")]
        public void Templatized(string input1, string operation, string input2, string expectedResult)
        {
            _driver.FindElementByName(input1).Click();
            _driver.FindElementByName(operation).Click();
            _driver.FindElementByName(input2).Click();
            _driver.FindElementByName("Equals").Click();

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, GetCalculatorResultText());
        }

        private string GetCalculatorResultText()
        {
            return _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CalculatorResults").Text.Replace("Display is", string.Empty).Trim();
        }
    }
}
```